# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I want to add extracted genre from IMDB to my Categories automatically.  I made JSON code to do this for me.

```
    $('input[name=Checkbx]').click(function() {
    var coc = $('input[name=Checkbx2]').get(0).value;
    // Send Request
    $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=" + coc + "&plot=short&r=json", function(data) {
        var valDir = "";
        var valWri = "";
        var valAct = "";    
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
              $('input[name=' +key+ ']').val(val); 
              if(key == "Director"){
                valDir+= " "+val+",";
              }   
if(key == "Genre"){
            var genr = "";
            $.each( data.Genre, function( key, val ) {
                genr += "" + val + ", ";
                genr1 = val;
                $('input[name=newcategory]').val( genr1 );
                $('#category-add-submit').trigger('click');
                 $('#category-add-submit').prop("disabled", false);
                $('input[name=newcategory]').val("");
            });
            $('input[name=' +key+ ']').val( genr );
        }
              if(key == "Actors"){
                valAct+= " "+val+",";
              }
              if(key == "Year"){
                $('#new-tag-<?php echo get_option('year'); ?>').val(val);
              }
              if(key == "Country"){
                $('#new-tag-movie-country').val(val);
              }
        });
        $('#new-tag-<?php echo get_option("director"); ?>').val(valDir);
        $('#new-tag-<?php echo get_option("actor"); ?>').val(valAct);
    }); 
});
```

For the record: I'm using omdbapi.com API for getting data from IMDB and my movie ID for test is `tt0111161` and the JSON output is:

```
{"Title":"The Shawshank Redemption","Year":"1994","Rated":"R","Released":"14 Oct 1994","Runtime":"142 min","Genre":"Crime, Drama","Director":"Frank Darabont","Writer":"Stephen King (short story \"Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption\"), Frank Darabont (screenplay)","Actors":"Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler","Plot":"Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"Nominated for 7 Oscars. Another 14 wins & 20 nominations.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODU4MjU4NjIwNl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDU2MjEyMDE@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"80","imdbRating":"9.3","imdbVotes":"1,610,411","imdbID":"tt0111161","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}
```

Everything works fine.  I mean Actors, Director and Casts are added automatically.  My problem is with Genres.

I've got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Crime, Drama
```

My JQuery version is 2.2.1.  How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"Genre"` field in your JSON looks like this:

```
"Genre":"Crime, Drama"
```

That is a single string containing two words separated by a comma. It is *not* an array containing two strings. You can't iterate over a single string using `$.each`.

You need to split the string into an array of strings first using [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
$.each( data.Genre.split(/\s*,\s*/), function( key, val ) {
```

This uses a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to split the `Genre` string at each comma (including possible white space). The result is an array `["Crime", "Drama"]` which `$.each` can iterate over.

Comment: Thank you very much. it works like a charm :D ...
another question.... for example i want to Replace "Crime" in this function with another word.. how can i do this ?